# meaning of system notifications

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I'm developing a service that uses HTTP updates over the Data network. It is used essentially outside.

Q1. the data icon is a triangle of vertical bars, but ir can have (a) an exclamation mark to the right, (b) and 'H' on top left, (c) it can be blank, or (d) full.

Where can I find a reference to what these (probably) useful indicators mean?

Comment: you can search for "android status bar icons"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the android status bar.

(a) When your cellphone is connected to a network, android tries to connect to a webpage to verify if internet is available. If the webpage is not reached, then an exclamation mark is shown, which may mean that you have a network connection, but you cannot reach external services.

(b) The meaning of H is the type of connection. G stands for GPRS, E for EDGE, H for HSDPA, H+ for HSUPA, and so on. They talk about the connection speed.

(c/d) If the triangles are blank or full depends on your connection signal. If your signal is strong, triangles are shown with full painting. If your signal is weak, triangles can be shown empty or something in the middle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspect my phone's cellular connection is 'weak'. Where do you get such knowledge from?

Comment: Android has a specific webpage for developers http://developer.android.com/index.html , if you go to develop you'll find more resources about android http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html . In this case I think that the important thing to know was the name of the status bar. With such information is easier to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

See your SDK, especially `<SDK>/platforms/<PLATFORM>/data/res` content.